# Neural Network for XOR approximation always outputs 0.5 for all inputs

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I've tried to implement the following neural network for XOR gate approximation. I've used the binary cross entropy for cost function. The cost always goes to around 0.69 and gets saturated. And for all inputs the network outputs 0.5. I've tried varying number of epochs, learning rate, number of layers but got no change. Where am I going wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

epsilon = 1e-15

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)


def sigmoid_backwards(A):
    return A * (1 - A)

def relu_backwards(A):
    return A >= 0

def init_parameters(layer_dims):
    paramters = {}
    L = len(layer_dims)
    for i in range(1, L):
        paramters['W' + str(i)] = np.random.randn(layer_dims[i], layer_dims[i-1]) * 0.001
        paramters['b' + str(i)] = np.zeros((layer_dims[i], 1))
    return paramters

def forward_pass(X, paramters, g):
    layer_vals = [X]
    A = X
    L = len(g)
    for i in range(1, L):
        A_prev = A
        Z = np.dot(paramters['W' + str(i)], A_prev) + paramters['b' + str(i)]
        A = activations[g[i]](Z)
        layer_vals.append(A)

    return layer_vals

def predict(X, paramters, g):
    layer_vals = [X]
    A = X
    L = len(g)
    for i in range(1, L):
        A_prev = A
        Z = np.dot(paramters['W' + str(i)], A_prev) + paramters['b' + str(i)]
        A = activations[g[i]](Z)
        layer_vals.append(A)

    return layer_vals[-1][0]


def backward_pass(y_true, layer_vals, paramters, g, learning_rate=0.01):
    m = y_true.shape[1]
    dA = -y_true/(layer_vals[-1] + epsilon) + (1-y_true)/(1-layer_vals[-1] + epsilon)
    for i in range(len(layer_vals)-1, 0, -1):
        dZ = dA * activations_backwards[g[i]](layer_vals[i])
        dA_prev = np.dot(paramters['W' + str(i)].T, dZ)
        dW = 1/m * np.dot(dZ, layer_vals[i-1].T)
        db = 1/m * np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        dA = dA_prev

        paramters['W' + str(i)] -= learning_rate * dW
        paramters['b' + str(i)] -= learning_rate * db

    return paramters

def compute_cost(y, output):
    m = y.shape[1]
    return -1/m * np.sum(y * np.log(output+epsilon) + (1-y) * np.log(1-output+epsilon))


activations = {
    'sigmoid': sigmoid,
    'relu': relu
}

activations_backwards = {
    'sigmoid': sigmoid_backwards,
    'relu': relu_backwards
}


X = np.array([[0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000],
              [0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]], dtype=float)
y = np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]], dtype=float)


layer_dims = (2, 3, 3, 1)
#g = ['linear', 'sigmoid', 'sigmoid', 'sigmoid']
g = ['linear', 'relu', 'relu', 'sigmoid']
epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01
paramters = init_parameters(layer_dims)
layer_vals = forward_pass(X, paramters, g)
costs = []
for i in range(epochs):
    parameters = backward_pass(y, layer_vals, paramters, g, learning_rate=learning_rate)
    layer_vals = forward_pass(X, paramters, g)
    cost = compute_cost(y, layer_vals[-1])
    costs.append(cost)
    if (i+1) % 10 == 0:
        print(f"After {i+1} epochs at learning rate {learning_rate:.4f}, cost: ", cost)

plt.plot(costs)
plt.show()
print(predict(X, paramters, g))
```

Here is the curve for cost function value
[Cost Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DesLm.png).
And the output is always
`[0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]`

Comment: Does your network learn anything simpler? Does it work when you take only one level and try to teach it something?

Comment: @Dimitry: With only one level (without any hidden layer) and simple linear separation of data the model seems to converge. But problem starts when I add hidden layers and try to classify non-linear data. I don't understand if the problem is in backprop implementation.

Comment: Well, the code is quite sizable, for those not in close touch with the matter it is difficult to spot anything wrong in it. One of the linked questions (this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369335/xor-neural-network-converges-to-0-5?rq=1 ) features the answer stating that it is a problem with back propagation. So I've meant to say you could first test a single sigmoid layer and track step by step how is it evolving.

Answer (score 0):

Nice try on neural nets; you're very close! Doing the following fixes your code:

1. You have a typo in `parameters = backward_pass()` that causes your parameters not do be updated.
2. Fixing this makes your network only converge in 1/1000 cases. Initializing your weights with std deviation of 1. and increasing #units per layer makes your code work perfectly!

Here's the working code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

epsilon = 1e-15

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x))


def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)


def sigmoid_backwards(A):
    return A * (1 - A)

def relu_backwards(A):
    return A >= 0

def init_parameters(layer_dims):
    paramters = {}
    L = len(layer_dims)
    for i in range(1, L):
        paramters['W' + str(i)] = np.random.randn(layer_dims[i], layer_dims[i-1]) * 1.
        paramters['b' + str(i)] = np.random.randn(layer_dims[i], 1) * 1. # np.zeros((layer_dims[i], 1))
    return paramters

def forward_pass(X, paramters, g):
    layer_vals = [X]
    A = X
    L = len(g)
    for i in range(1, L):
        A_prev = A
        Z = np.dot(paramters['W' + str(i)], A_prev) + paramters['b' + str(i)]
        A = activations[g[i]](Z)
        layer_vals.append(A)

    return layer_vals

def predict(X, paramters, g):
    layer_vals = [X]
    A = X
    L = len(g)
    for i in range(1, L):
        A_prev = A
        Z = np.dot(paramters['W' + str(i)], A_prev) + paramters['b' + str(i)]
        A = activations[g[i]](Z)
        layer_vals.append(A)

    return layer_vals[-1][0]


def backward_pass(y_true, layer_vals, paramters, g, learning_rate=0.01):
    m = y_true.shape[1]
    dA = -y_true/(layer_vals[-1] + epsilon) + (1-y_true)/(1-layer_vals[-1] + epsilon)
    #dA = -y_true * np.log(layer_vals[-1]+epsilon) + (1.-y_true) * np.log(1-layer_vals[-1]+epsilon)
    #print('dAnew', dA)
    for i in range(len(layer_vals)-1, 0, -1):
        #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        dZ = dA * activations_backwards[g[i]](layer_vals[i])
        dA_prev = np.dot(paramters['W' + str(i)].T, dZ)
        dW = 1/m * np.dot(dZ, layer_vals[i-1].T)
        db = 1/m * np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        dA = dA_prev
        paramters['W' + str(i)] -= learning_rate * dW
        paramters['b' + str(i)] -= learning_rate * db

    return paramters

def compute_cost(y, output):
    m = y.shape[1]
    return -1/m * np.sum(y * np.log(output+epsilon) + (1-y) * np.log(1-output+epsilon))


activations = {
    'sigmoid': sigmoid,
    'relu': relu
}

activations_backwards = {
    'sigmoid': sigmoid_backwards,
    'relu': relu_backwards
}


X = np.array([[0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000],
              [0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]], dtype=float)
y = np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]], dtype=float)


layer_dims = (2, 32, 32, 1)
#g = ['linear', 'sigmoid', 'sigmoid', 'sigmoid']
g = ['linear', 'relu', 'relu', 'sigmoid']
epochs = 10000
learning_rate = 0.001
paramters = init_parameters(layer_dims)
layer_vals = forward_pass(X, paramters, g)
costs = []
for i in range(epochs):
    paramters = backward_pass(y, layer_vals, paramters, g, learning_rate=learning_rate)
    layer_vals = forward_pass(X, paramters, g)
    cost = compute_cost(y, layer_vals[-1])
    costs.append(cost)
    if (i+1) % 10 == 0:
        print(f"After {i+1} epochs at learning rate {learning_rate:.4f}, cost: ", cost)

plt.plot(costs)
plt.savefig("delete.png")
print(predict(X, paramters, g))
```

Comment: Well, typo in the variable "parameters" was definitely a problem. Another problem I found is in the "relu_backwards(A)" function where the return statement should be "return A > 0" (Not A>=0)(As 'A' in this case is the relu output). After fixing these problems and increasing #units per layer as per your suggestion the model converges quickly in less than 100 epochs.